# jquery <a> tag click event

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post

I am building a code which displays user information on search. User information, is then displayed in a `fieldset`, and a image, first name, last name and few profile info. is shown, and in the bottom of the `fieldset`, there's  a add as friend hyperlink:

```
<a href="#" id="aaf">add as friend</a>
```

Now I want to use jquery `$post()` method to interact with another page. I also have a hidden field inside that user `fieldset` which has the user id value. Now, when i create a click functionality using `jquery`, i am not able to access the different hidden field values. Now i want to know how to achieve this functionality? For checking if i can get the value of hidden fields inside a set of code, i did this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a#aaf").bind('click', function () {
        alert($("#uid").val());
    });
});
```

But I'm only getting the value of first `fieldset`, not others. Kindly guide me in this.

EDIT: How to get it in each tag click event? I'm putting some more code here,

```
<?php foreach($query->result() as $row){?>
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <?php echo $row->firstname.' '.$row->lastname;?>
    </legend>
    <img src='<?php echo $row->profile_img_url;?>'/><br>
    <a href="#" id="aaf">add as friend</a>
    <input name="uid" type="hidden" value='<?php echo $row->uid;?>' id="uid">
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="aaf" id="users_id">add as a friend</a>
```

on jquery

```
$('.aaf').on("click",function(){
  var usersid =  $(this).attr("id");
  //post code
})
```

//other method is to use the data attribute

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="aaf" data-id="102" data-username="sample_username">add as a friend</a>
```

on jquery

```
$('.aaf').on("click",function(){
    var usersid =  $(this).data("id");
    var username = $(this).data("username");
})
```

Comment: Note .live() is depreciated in the newest jQueries. Use .on() instead.

Answer (score 5):

That's because your hidden fields have duplicate IDs, so jQuery only returns the first in the set. Give them classes instead, like `.uid` and grab them via:

```
var uids = $(".uid").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/FtcnJ/

EDIT: say your output looks like the following (notice, IDs have changed to classes)

```
<fieldset><legend>John Smith</legend>
<img src='foo.jpg'/><br>
<a href="#" class="aaf">add as friend</a>
<input name="uid" type="hidden" value='<?php echo $row->uid;?>' class="uid">
</fieldset>
```

You can target the 'uid' relative to the clicked anchor like this:

```
$("a.aaf").click(function() {
    alert($(this).next('.uid').val());
});
```

Important: do not have any duplicate IDs. They will cause problems. They are *invalid*, *bad* and you should *not* do it.

Comment: ok, i will try this out, and will let u guys know abt it..thanks for it.

Answer (score 2):

All the hidden fields in your fieldset are using the same id, so jquery is only returning the first one. One way to fix this is to create a counter variable and concatenate it to each hidden field id.